# Mips instruction with 32 zeros

Tags: assembly, mips

I was asking myself why an instruction with all 32 bits as zeros in MIPS is considered a NOP instruction. I mean what if "op, rs, rt, rd, shamt and funct" were all zero? Which operation corresponds to this instruction?

Comment: what did you find when you looked it up, or disassembled it?

Answer (score 1):

`0x00000000` = `sll r0,r0,0`, which ie effectively a `NOP`.

Answer (score 1):

The SLL instruction with RD, RT and SHAMT field set to 0 has no side effects. 
Instruction: `SLL $0, $0, 0`

In fact the encodings for a No-Op represents the SLL instruction with the above parameters. It is also true for MIPS that any instruction that has $0 as its destination register will have no side effect and can thus be considered as kind of No-Op operation.